# Home wireless lock

Tags: doors, lock

How can I improve my home with a kind of front door lock that would act like those car that can unlock when it receive signal of the key in your pant?

My goal would be to keep my keys in my pant without having to use them everytime I am near of the door.

What is your suggestion?

Comment: It sounds like you want a proximity sensor, so you don't even have to push a button.

Comment: If you do this, make sure you don't leave your keys/phone near the door when you get home.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I usually keep them in my pocket all the time. And this is why I would need a small range. 1 or 2 meters would be perfect.

Comment: How about a small RFID tag implanted under the skin, then install a reader hooked up to an actuator to unlock the door. Then every time you walked near the door it would just unlock automatically, no need to carry keys!

Answer (score 3):

[Here is a device](http://www.smarthome.com/70471/ECKey-EK3-Bluetooth-enabled-Professional-Relay-Unit/p.aspx) that allows you to unlock the door via Bluetooth.

[Here](http://blog.10100111001.com/2009/01/open-frontdoor-using-bluetooth.html) is a home-brew device built by an electronics enthusiast.

A while ago I heard about this and i really wanted to do it with my house as well.

In terms of security, it is secure as long as you have your phone with you and nobody can hack the signal. You pair with the Bluetooth lock once using a strong password, then on each sync it checks the phones MAC address and Password. This makes it difficult to spoof the key (but a strong password is still important).

Some more references

http://www.labnol.org/gadgets/unlock-car-door-with-mobile-phone/4892/

http://www.ohgizmo.com/2009/05/21/use-bluetooth-signals-to-open-your-garage-door/

Answer (score 3):

You can find this one [Morning Industry Brass Remote-Controlled Keyless Entry Knob](http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?storeId=10051&productId=100530062&langId=-1&catalogId=10053&ci_sku=100530062&ci_src=14110944&cm_mmc=shopping-_-googlebase-_-D27X-_-100530062), at [Home Depot](http://www.homedepot.com) for $112.00.

[image: Morning Industry Brass Remote-Controlled Keyless Entry Knob]

> **Description:**
>
> Never worry about losing keys or
> fumbling around with door locks again
> with the Morning Industries Brass
> Remote-Controlled Keyless Entry Knob.
> This door knob utilizes
> radio-frequency technology to open and
> comes with a pair of remote controls
> that fit conveniently on key chains.
>
> - Keyless door lock allows remote-control entry
> - Brass finish
> - Supports usage with up to 15 different remote controls
> - Auto-lock function re-locks the knob automatically 10 seconds after
>   every unlock
> - Anti-scan code-hopping technology prevents intruders from hacking into
>   the lock's radio frequency
> - Distinct audible tones provide notifications for locking, unlocking,
>   jams and low battery
> - Installation involves no wiring
> - Includes 2 keychain remote controls, 2 keys for emergency use and
>   an adjustable backset
> - MFG Brand Name : Morning Industry
> - MFG Model # : 51891
> - MFG Part # : 51891

This seems to be exactly what you are looking for. The installation does not seem to be any more difficult than the installation of a traditional lock, so it should be a very DIY friendly project.

*NOTICE: I have never used this product, so I can not encourage nor endorse it's use.  Use at your own risk.*

Comment: This is what I want :)

Comment: I would be very carefull with these locks! The remote sends a signal via 900Mhz that anybody can intercept and save (like a car remote) then easy to get into your house if somebody knows how!!! And.. they dont even need to get your signal becuase they can use a signal generator to brute force the lock with spam signals.. and poof- open. For BEST securioty you need 2 way authentication-- like the bluetooth MAC ADRESS challenges PASSWORD.

Comment: @ppumkin: maybe so, but it does say it has "Anti-scan code-hopping technology" to prevent intruders from hacking the frequency.  I'm not saying this is the most secure system, just showing the OP that there are systems available that do what they want.

Comment: Nice thing about this is that you have to actually push the button.  I don't like the idea of the door unlocking every time I walk near it, particularly if you're going to the door to investigate a possible intruder with your phone or keys in your hand.

Comment: I am search something that will unlock without having to press anything. That defeat the purpose if I have to go in my pocket getting the remote. What I search is something that when I am under 1 or 2 meters that it unlock.

Comment: @Daok: They have what you describe in some vehicles, so I would guess a home version is not too far off.  I cannot find any products on the web that match all your requirements, most proximity locks require a "fob" or "smart card" and only have a read distance of an inch or so.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a website that use "RFID". Never hear about it but it seems to be a solution.

Here is the link http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-RFID-Door-Lock/

Answer (score 1):

Your big-box Home Depot-like store sells keyless entries that work just like your car locks.

Comment: Do you have a link because I can't find them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something from [Kwikset](http://www.kwikset.com/SmartSecurity/Wireless-Technology.aspx).  Not sure if it has a keychain remote though.  Just DAGS for "wireless door lock home" and I'm sure you'll get all kinds of results.

Comment: When I type that on Google I just get stuff that let me open my door from internet. I want something like for car. Something that just let me open it when I am under 1 or 2 meters.

Comment: Really deserves a minus.. as not on topic..